# how to dynamically changing image name & tags on kustomize.yaml using github actions?

Tags: github-actions, docker-image, kustomize, github-ci, docker-tag

if i have my kustomize.yaml file here :

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

images:
- name: nix/image
  newName: nix/image2
  newTag: latest
```

and i want to dynamically change the values of the new generated image & tags after building with github actions to be edited on Kustomize.yaml file and here is my github actions :

```
name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: folder1
          file: ./folder1/Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/image3:v1.0
```

can anyone edit this one to dynamically change the values of newName & newTag on kustomize.yaml file after build with github actions ? tnx

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: i already solved it tnx alot :) @frennky